# C# dll cannot find a file on a project

Tags: c#, dll

I'm building a dotnet Library, the Library needs to access a Folder/txt file from the project and save a FolderB/zip file in the project. All the folders are located in the project.

Reference

- MyDll
  Project
- FolderA/txt
- FolderB/zip

When I run the code that reads the file I get : Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ML.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Het
systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Well it sounds like you're using Microsoft.ML.Data, but haven't made that available in your application. Please give us more context about the application itself, given that you can't be running the library directly.